# No global application menu for Aptana Studio 3

Tags: 11.04, unity, appmenu

I installed Aptana 3 in ubuntu 11.04, unity and found the global menu integration is not proper. How can I have global menu support for Aptana ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found you can do the following at the command line (src: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/659931):

```
$ UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=
```

Then start the application:

```
./studio3
```

I edited the "studio3" starter script adding

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=
```

as the 3rd or 4th line to make this change permanent. Make a backup before you edit "studio3", to be safe.

Comment: @Nikhil Maybe you should reconsider what answer answered your question since this answer might how to add global menu support.

Answer (score 2):

Many applications don't have global menu integration yet, and chances are, you probably can't have it, at least for now. You could try filing a bug report or contacting the project devs, and state your case.

Answer (score 1):

I got it right working :) ***(Although not Global Menu, atleast I get all menu options)***

Here is the solution http://blog.lukebennett.com/2011/07/05/menu-issue-with-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-11-0/

Dont forget to replace `./AptanaStudio3`with `./TitaniumStudio`

Here is the full script that I used,

```
#!/bin/bash
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
./TitaniumStudio
```

A screenshot of my titanium studio with menu (Although not global menu, the menu options will be displayed in unity)

[image]